# Not sure about this limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, inequality

Evaluate:

$\lim \limits_{n \to +\infty}$ $(sin^2(3+sin(n)))^n$

Knowing that $-1 \le sin(n) \le 1$

$(sin^2(4))^n\le(sin^2(3+sin(n)))^n\le(sin^2(2))^n$

Since $sin^2(2)$ and $sin^2(4)$ are both $\in(-1,1)$, they $\to0$ as $n\to+\infty$, so the limit is $0$ for squeeze theorem.

Is it right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can bind it tighter thatn that!  $0\le \sin^2 (3 +\sin n) < \sin^2 2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You squeezed it wrong. $sin(4)\le sin(3+sin(n))\le sin(2)$ does not imply $(sin^2(4))^n\le(sin^2(3+sin(n)))^n\le(sin^2(2))^n$.

You should instead use $0\le|sin(3+sin(n))|\le \max \{|\sin(2)|,|\sin(4)|\}=c<1$, then $0\le|sin(3+sin(n))|^n\le c^n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|sin(3+sin(n))|^n=0$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain me why it doesn't imply that? Because it isn't monotonic in without a restriction? And why we have "ignored" the squared quantity in the second part of the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @IWishIWasRiemann Imagine that, if for some even values of $n$, $\sin{(3+\sin{(n)})}$ is very close to $0$, then $|\sin{(3+\sin{(n)})}|\le |\sin{(4)}|$, so $(sin^2(3+sin(n)))^n\le(sin^2(4))^n$. In general, if $a<b<c$, you can't conclude $a^n<b^n<c^n$, because the sign issue. Example: $-10 < -9< 1$, but $1^2<(-9)^2<(-10)^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}:0\leq\sin^{2n}(x)\leq 1$$

If you multiply a positive number strictly smaller than 1 with it self it gets smaller. This happens to all the values where $\sin^2(x)$ has no local maximum. The maxima are all 1. So $\sin^{2n}(x)$ for larger $n$ gets spikier around its maxima, sharply dropping to 0 on all other values. Finally since between 2 and 4 there is no maximum, the limit must be 0.